# Can't open png, saved with Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, png, gimp

Recently I started studying Android development. To get myself started I'm trying to develop a simple app to track my favorite coffee cups. To this end, I thought I'd download the images [(sample)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c4d6ly93j8osvj2/9148239937566.png?dl=0) of the cups from the official [website](https://www.nespresso.com/ch/en/coffee-grid#!/by-range). The good news is that I can right-click and save them as .png files and Android (Studio) can display them. The challenge I have is that I can't open these png's (e.g. to view or edit) in any other program. I've tried Windows Paint, Photo viewer, IE, GIMP... none work. The only program I can view the images with is Chrome. Of course this doesn't help me edit them.

I've searched for answers, but can't find any.
I've tried renaming to .webp and .jpg, hoping this could do the trick.
I've tried online file type identifier (checkfiletype.com), which then indicates it's a RIFF file, which doesn't seem very helpful, since it is an image and no audio.
When I download the images via e.g. Firefox or IE, I get different file formats, which seem to be significantly larger file size, so I'd prefer to use the Chrome downloads.

I'm out of options. Would anyone know how to get these files opened/edited?
Preferably I'd be able to open with GIMP. At the moment however I'd even be happy to simply settle to be able to view them outside of Chrome.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZPcm.png I had no problem opening it and straightening it.

Comment: How did you download?
From nespresso.ch? By right-clicking and "save image as..."?
From Dropbox? (for Dropbox:) did you save the preview or open the original? (I can save the preview from dropbox and open, but I can't open the original)

Comment: from dropbox, right click- save image as..

Comment: That means you've downloaded the dropbox preview, which indeed opens fine as a .png. It probably won't work (at least it doesn't for me) when you open/download the original instead. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the extension, it is not a PNG but a [Web/P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP) image:

```
14:21:51 tmp/ >identify -verbose Sample-9148239937566.png 
identify: delegate failed `"dwebp" -pam "%i" -o "%o"' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1310.
identify: unable to open image `/tmp/magick-30698uSxzl_4IFlIA': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.
identify: unable to open file `/tmp/magick-30698uSxzl_4IFlIA': No such file or directory @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/540.
14:22:10 tmp/ >file Sample-9148239937566.png 
Sample-9148239937566.png: RIFF (little-endian) data, Web/P image
```

To open it with Gimp you would need a [plugin](https://github.com/nathan-osman/gimp-webp).

Application that determine filetype based on [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) can open them without problem (if they support the format). Others (like Firefox) need to see the proper file extension (rename the file to `*.webp`).